# Need concept for a particular type apps in c#

Tags: c#, architecture

I have developed a Windows application where a button is there on a form and when button is clicked then few series of functions will run one after one like below one

```
Button_Click()

{

function1();

function2();

function3();

function4();

function5();

function6();

function7();

function8();

function9();

function101();

function1();

function12();

function13();

}
```

Each function does some jobs. so my apps is working fine but i need to know how to design this sort of job in more structure way. so please guide me how structure way i can call all function one after one. how a experienced & expert developer will  handle this jobs or how they call function one after one. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all depends on if the functions need to be invoked in a specific order or not.

If not: Use a pub/sub pattern.

If a specific order is required:

Do not use functions, add the functions to classes and use a pipeline like below.

```
public interface IPipeline
{
    void AddLast(IPipelineHandler handler);
    void AddFirst(IPipelineHandler handler);

    void Invoke(IPipelineContext context);
}

public interface IPipelineContext
{
   Form SourceForm {get; }

   // The result that the pipeline should produce.  (change from object to a specific type)
   object Result {get; }

   //and other properties that each handler will need.
}

public interface IPipelineHandler
{
    string Name {get; }
    void Process(IPipelineContext context);
}
```

In the pipeline implementation, invoke each handler with the same context:

```
public void Invoke(IPipelineContext context)
{
     foreach (handler in _handlers)
     {
        try
        {
             handler.Process(context);
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            //abort or continue with the next handler?
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: your code is good but i am not being able to understand how can i use it in my scenario. basically i am not very advance user. it would be better if u please give me full code where all my function1(),function2() so on etc will be called one after another with ur above code. thanks. i just need to see how my function can be called with ur implementation. plzz help me. thanks

Answer (score 3):

- Give your entitiess meaningful names
- Give your entitiess meaningful names
- Give your entitiess meaningful names
- Give your entitiess meaningful names
- Extract functions for common code
- Possibly signals/slots / listener / observer concepts are for you.

edit: Refactoring Example:

Suppose your code is:

```
void Button1_Click() {
    function1();
    function2();
    function3();
    function4();
    function5();
}    
void Button2_Checked(int variable0) {
    if (variable0) {
        function1();
        function2();
    } else {
        function1();
        function2();
        function3();     
        function4();
        function5();
    }
}
```

Step 0-10 is to find meaningful names for all, the buttons, the functions, 
the variables, the parameters (only rename one entity a time; I skipped this for sake of post):

```
void orderPizzaButton_Click() {
    requestSalamis();
    requestAnchovis();        
    requestShitake();        
    requestCheese();
    requestGroundMeat();
}    
void lasagnePervesityLevel_Changed(int newValue) {
    if (newValue <= 0) {
        requestCheese();
        requestGroundMeat();
    } else {
        requestSalamis();
        requestAnchovis();        
        requestShitake();
        requestCheese();
        requestGroundMeat();
    }
}
```

Step 11 is to find commons in those functions, and extract a new, re-usable function
from them:

```
void orderPizzaButton_Click() {
    requestStrangeIngredientCombination();
}    
void lasagnePervesityLevel_Changed(int newValue) {
    if (newValue <= 0) {
        requestCheese();
        requestGroundMeat();
    } else {
        requestStrangeIngredientCombination();
    }
}

void requestStrangeIngredientCombination() {
    requestSalamis();
    requestAnchovis();        
    requestShitake();
    requestCheese();
    requestGroundMeat();
}
```

Step 12 is to refine your search of common code (think of it as a kind of normalization):

```
void orderPizzaButton_Click() {
    requestStrangeIngredientCombination();
}
void lasagnePervesityLevel_Changed(int newValue) {
    if (newValue <= 0) {
        requestStandardComponents();
    } else {
        requestStrangeIngredientCombination();
    }
}

void requestStandardComponents() {
    requestCheese();
    requestGroundMeat();
}
void requestStrangeIngredientCombination() {
    requestSalamis();
    requestAnchovis();        
    requestShitake();
    requestStandardComponents();
}
```

While in this example it seems that you didn't save code, in reality it often **will**. Also, saving lines of code is not the important thing here, the thing is about reducing redundancy, because once you decide your perverse lasagne and strange pizza should also hold chilis and an image of Sylvester Stallone, you will not only have code-duplication, but **work-duplication**; and most importantly, there is the potential to forget the new features in some places of your code. This, of course, is very bad and even business critical. Suppose your customers expect an image of Sylvester Stallone on their lasagne, just as your marketing campaign promised, and then no one who ordered pizza ever gets that image, but just those ppl who ordered lasagne.

Many more refactorings and designs exist, depending on the actual code. I really
recommend to get the following books. Also, most important rule of thumb: One step a time. Do exactly one small refactoring, compile, test.

- *Refactoring - Improving the Design of Existing Code* by Martin Fowler at Addison-Wesley
- *C++ Coding Standards: 101 Rules, Guidelines and Best Practices C++* by Herb Sutter, Andrei Alexandrescu (C++ In-Depth series) at Addison-Wesley
- *Design Patterns: Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software* by Gamma, Helm, Johnson, Vlissides (commonly called GoF, for Gang of Four), once again at Addison-Wesley

Comment: which design pattern i should follow for handling this situation. can u please show sample code to handle this situation.

Comment: I am not sure if this really deserves a design pattern. It should be common programmer sense to name things meaningfully, and to put repeated stuff into seperate, re-usable entities. I'll give an example.

Answer (score 0):

If the functionality you are creating needs these functions to be performed in that order, then why not encapsulate those calls within a method? This will give you a higher level of encapsulation, and mean that this function could be called elsewhere, say from a menu toolbar, without having to worry so much if all the functions are called in the correct order.

It is also worth assigning more meaningful names to your functions, but I'm sure you are only naming them as functionX() for example purposes.

So, for example:

```
Button_Click()
{
   Print()
}

private void Print()
{
  function1();
  function2();
  function3();
  function4();
  function5();
  function6();
  function7();
  function8();
  function9();
  function10();
  function11();
  function12();
  function13();
}
```

Comment: And a higher level of abstraction, which can improve code readability. If this functionality is performed elsewhere, then you are making one call, not 14. This can also be better unit tested through mocking. ---EDIT--- Hmm, it seems the person I'm responding to deleted their comment.

Comment: May be Button_Click is already encapsulates these functions? So you wrote same thing.

Comment: Of course, that is true. With example code as such it is difficult to know the full domain. Button_Click() indicated a .NET click handling pattern to me, hence the response. So if Button_Click() is a level of encapsulation, then my comment about more meaningful function names has more relevancy. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: here i give u the pesudo code and that is why i did not specify meaningful name.

Comment: I thought that would be the case :) Hope my answer helps!

Comment: which design pattern i should follow for handling this situation in a very professional wau. can u please show sample code to handle this situation.

Comment: It depends on your requirements, there is the risk of over-engineering a solution. Flow of control means your functions are called sequentially. It seems that you don't need any more than that. Professionalism will come from unit testing this functionality, not throwing design patterns at it. That way, you will be able to show the functionality works, and can be refactored safely if more requirements come in later.

Answer (score 0):

What answer do you expect? Without knowing how that functions are related to each other no one can answer this.

Does the functions depend on each other? Does the next function have to wait before the previous ones have been completed? Or may they run in parallel? Are these functions always the same or can they change? Maybe you want to configure them, thus making the calls that the button performs dynamic. Maybe even at runtime?

If you do not have any of that requirements, I see no problem with your current code.

You should have a look at design patterns like the Command Pattern or the Pipes & Filters Pattern, maybe this helps you.

Comment: i just want to know how my situation can be handle with a right design pattern. functions does not depend on each other. yes next function will wait before prev one complete. functions will be always same. so now tell me with small code to implement the situation with right design pattern. thanks

Comment: In this case, your current code is fine. Are you having any trouble with your code, what makes you think that your code is wrong?